# Test OpenSQL statements in the SAP GUI or Eclipse ADT?

Tags: abap, opensql

I am writing an OpenSQL query, including joins and sub-selects, and I am unsure whether it works. To find out, I'd like to run it somewhere, look at the results, then change it, it an iterative way.

Traditional tools like transactions `SE16` or `SQVI` don't help, because they have too little functionality (only one table, only joins but no sub-selects, etc.). Other threads with similar questions, [like this one](https://it.toolbox.com/question/execute-sql-query-in-sap-020614) remained unanswered.

Of course, I could write a report or a unit test, paste my code there, and run it, but this makes the iterative cycle so slow because I need to change input and output data formats all the time. Optimal solution would be something like the SQL Console in SAP HANA Studio, but for OpenSQL instead of native SQL.

Comment: Agree with guettli. This may sound like a “what tools are there to ...” biased question but it’s actually a non-biased technology question.

Comment: Can you be more precise with what you mean by “test”? Test as “how can I write unit tests for this”? Or test as in “not sure if it compiles and need to trial-and-error my way around the code”?

Comment: @Florian I updated the question and explained what I mean with "test".

Comment: https://sta-technologies.com/opensql-editor-for-sap/ There is a 30 days trial period, so might be a short term solution only (unless your company buys it)

Comment: Let's see whether my rewrite changes the on-hold?

Comment: Why would you need to "change input and output data formats all the time"? INTO TABLE @DATA and generic salv display should work all the time

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai very interesting, and it handles FOR ALL ENTRIES too. Do you mind adding your answer to "mine" (community wiki) if the "on-hold" permits it?

Comment: @SandraRossi: yes, of course, no need to ask at all :)

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377092/question-about-programming-language-abap-was-closed-by-people-who-seem-to-have-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. (on behalf of @Florian) Use the **[SQL console](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/26/sql-console-in-aie/)** in Eclipse. it allows Open SQL SELECT, except `FOR ALL ENTRIES` and variables.
2. (on behalf of @JozsefSzikszai) [software "OpenSQL Editor for SAP", by STA Consulting Kft.](https://sta-technologies.com/opensql-editor-for-sap) There is a 30 days trial period, so might be a short term solution only (unless your company buys it)
3. Use the tool **`ZTOAD`**, created by Sébastien Hermann : http://quelquepart.biz/article7/ztoad-requeteur-open-sql.
4. You may indirectly test the Open SQL statements by creating test classes (ABAP Unit), in which you use the class **`CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`** (ABAP >= 7.52), which is used to mock the database, so you may provide false data, enter the expected result, execute the open SQL in test mode, and verify that actual result = expected result. It supports all Open SQL features.
5. All the above solutions allow testing Open SQL directly. Another solution is to use native SQL editors, and to write the Open SQL statements in the Strict mode (ABAP >= 7.40) so that they are closer to the native SQL syntax (especially the comma is to be used to separate the column names; but the alias separator has to be manually changed from `~` to `.`). There are two native SQL editors: one is a tool in **`ST04 or ST04N`**, one is the standard program **`RSDU_EXEC_SQL`**. Both display the result of SELECT statements in an ALV grid.

Comment: I think there is a 4th way with the ABAP Development Tools: press F8 on a data source (such as a transparent table) to “test” it. This opens a data preview. There is a second tab attached with the OpenSQL query that produced the preview. If I remember correctly this accepts fully fledged OpenSQL statements. Maybe check and add it to your answer?

Comment: @Florian, right, the "SQL console" in Eclipse. It's native SQL only so the answer for RSDU_EXEC_SQL applies to the SQL console too. I try to convert my answer into "community wiki" so that you can contribute.

Comment: Solution1: RSDU_EXEC_SQL uses native SQL. I need open sql. Solution2: looks good. Needs installation, but this would be possible (not tried yet). Solution3: My sap version is lower then 7.52. Thank you for the link to ZTOAD!

Comment: @Sandra, I don't mean the "SQL Console" in the SAP HANA Studio - that's native SQL directly on the database, true. But I think there is a different one *in Eclipse's ABAP perspective* that accepts OpenSQL. At least it uses the ABAP syntax. But not sure what it's capable of. Unfortunately got no machine to test this right now...

Comment: @Florian as far as I can see F8 does a preview of SELECT * and there's a button to start the SQL console to edit the SQL statement and run it again. In fact, I see that the accepted SQL is a mix between Open SQL and Native SQL. The tilde must be used for the aliases and `INTO ...` may be left although ignored (so it's Open SQL) and all Open SQL functions are allowed, but a few features are not accepted (like `FOR ALL ENTRIES`) and you must replace variables with constants. **So you're right, the SQL console is more a Open SQL editor**, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: What if I get "You are not authorized to use this tool" when I try to run `RSDU_EXEC_SQL`. I have SAP_ALL and SAP_NEW, i.e. all authorizations. How to fix that?

Comment: I use the SQL console in eclipse sometimes. But i am disappointed as some code - which are examples in sap f1 help - do not work. Missing in my experience are the new selection mode with "Fields", or sql command "left" or Group By with Alias-Column names.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,
you could take a look into queries (SQ01/SQ02) instead of QuickViews in SQVI. In Queries you have a chance to enhance your Joins with coding and you are still able to test your "code". For incremental changes this might be your easiest way to go.

Regards